# Inheritance with variables overriding

Tags: less

I have defined a class `.class` which uses a variable `@var`:

```
@var: 'value';

.class {
    property: @var;
    // and much more stuff [...]
}
```

And now I want to inherit from `.class` and change the value of `@var` in the same time like this:

```
.another-class {
    @var: 'another-value';
    .class;
}
```

But it seems the new value `another-value` is not taken. How can I achieve this without changing `.class`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this question seems to be a duplicate of "[Can I override global variables from the calling scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298547)". And I found an answer in its comments (https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/9473260) but this changes the original class a little bit:

```
@var: 'value';

.lib() {
    .class() {
        property: @var;
        // and the rest of `.class`
    }
}

.class {
    .lib.class();
}

.another-class {
    @var: 'another-value';
    .lib.class();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I'd suggest in a simplest case is just a *parametric* mixin, e.g.:

```
@var: value;

.mixin(@parameter: @var) {
    property: @parameter;
}

.class {
    .mixin();
}

.another-class {
    .mixin(another-value);
}
```

(Unless you need to override too many variables so that the mixin becomes too verbose... But in this case the idea of re-using the styles turns to be flawed itself. A better solution to choose may be too dependable on the real code (what exactly the `.class` is about and what actually it's doing in context of CSS).

There's looooong discussion about similar use-cases in general at [#2435](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2435#issuecomment-73838176), there're [detailed](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2435#issuecomment-73151734) explanation of [why](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2435#issuecomment-72986205) actually Less works this way (`global scope` > `caller scope`) and other insights of various pros and cons of parameterizing of a mixin via variable overriding instead of explicit parameter passing and/or explicit CSS property overriding).

Comment: Agreed, this seems to be the better option.

Comment: Disagreed when you use within this class more then 10 global vars and the class is one 10 or 20. The alternative approach of yours is totally fine ;).

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer if you have 10 variables to set (thus it's at least 10 properties differ in your new class) then it seems totally wrong to re-use that base ruleset as mixin at all. One would set all these new CSS properties directly ([like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/9c3a71b18eb9c784d1d6#file-28949678-less) for example).

Comment: Sorry but you don't know my "special" scenario here: I need to adapt a responsive layout for a whole site multiple times, because I'm using it in the back-end of TYPO3 Neos. It's hard to explain in some sentences but in short: I have the selector `body.tool-bar-left` => change all media queries to `sm-min-width: x + bar-size`, `body.tool-bar-left.tool-bar-right` => change media queries to `sm-min-width: x + bar-size * 2` [...]. This means in the back-end all styles must copied for each case (closed or opened tool bar) to simulate the right screen size.

Comment: @witrin You can simply isolate each "specific layout" in `& {}` (or even in each specific `body.xxx {} ` if that fits)` and import file with those reused rulesets right into there and then you are free to override these changing variables per each case. (I even suspect that in this case you won't need to explicitly invoke rulesets as mixins as they become "self-generating"... Well, maybe not, yet again everything is too dependable on the exact code).

Comment: Hm maybe you're right with the `@import` within a `body.xxx {}` mixin as long as I'm able to overwrite some variables of the imported rules in that `body.xxx` and the possibility to reuse a mixin with all imports, this might be the better option because I have not to encapsulate each file with those mixins. I'll try that this weekend and link here an example...